# Teradata: How do you debug "Transaction ABORTed due to Deadlock" errors?

Tags: deadlock, teradata

Lately, we've been getting hit with the error `Transaction ABORTed due to Deadlock` when we go to update a record in one of our tables.  Something is placing a lock on this table and it's not being released, but I have spent literal work days trying to track it down and it eludes me still.

While the error is random, I do know what repetive cycle of steps I need to repeat in order to eventually trigger it.  However, I've queried dbc.DBQLogTbl and looked at all the SQL that's been executed 2 minutes before and after the error occurs and nothing appears to be selecting from any table without an access lock.  Furthermore, after the error occurs, I will hit F5 repost the web form back to the server to repeat the exact same set of updates and it will work.

My hunch is that some process outside our ASP.NET application is locking the table since I've checked all the SQL that's being executed by our application.  I think there has to be a way to find out what specific SQL has been executed that has placed locks on a table.

**8/9/2012 Additional info:**  All of the following is occuring in this order within the same transaction based on what I am seeing when querying `dbc.DBQLogTbl` and ordering by `firststeptime`:

- update employee table
- locking row for access select * from employeesecurity where empid = X (do this to get current employee record to see if anything has changed)
- if there is a change, update aforementioned employeesecurity record
- update employeeconfig table (deadlock error always occurs here)

I didn't mention this before, but the deadlock error is occurring on a table that I am not selecting from at all.  When the page loads, I do read from an employeeconfig view, but `locking row for access` is specified in the view.

Answer to Rob's 4 questions:

- It's only one transaction.
- As I stated in my latest update, the table that's locked is not even the table that's being selected from.
- All queries use `locking row for access`
- We are selecting from the view `employeeconfig`.  This view selects from the `employeeconfig` table using `locking row for access`.  We do not use `locking row for access` when querying the view itself.

As far as handling the deadlock, I'd rather not have the code just try to resubmit it as this seems like a problem that needs to be fixed.  As you said, Rob, it's possible that my access to `dbc.DBQLogTbl` is limited, so perhaps I just cannot see everything that is occurring.  I've been in contact with the DBA and will follow up again today.

Comment: I would consider that if you encounter a deadlock error your application attempts at least once to retry the aborted transaction. Does your environment use Viewpoint? If so, are you allowed to use it with the Rewind feature and Query Monitor portlet?

Comment: Yes, we use viewpoint, but I have been unsuccessful in figuring it out.  I try to use the session ID I get from querying dbc.DBQLogTbl, but ViewPoint never seems to find it.  Additionaly, the SQL tab in the query monitor is always greyed out.  Is there any other method of finding out what SQL has a lock on a table or is ViewPoint pretty much the only option?

Comment: Viewpoint would just help identify the other sessions that were active at the time your transaction was aborted. The SQL may not be visible depending on the portlet permissions that were set for your role on Viewpoint. (See DBA Team.)

Comment: What is the locking level that is being applied to the 'EmployeeConfig' table for the update statement? I am assuming you are performing a single row update and qualifying on the Primary Index.

Comment: Yep, single-row update on primary index.  I am not specifying any locking for the update.  Basically, I am just using `update employeeconfig set field = x where id = y`.

Comment: See answer for details on using ROW EXCLUSIVE locking for your UPDATE statement. Try that and see if you can replicate/eliminate the deadlock.

Comment: I tried that with my UPDATE and I got `[Teradata Database] [3778] SELECT statement must follow LOCK ROW modifier.`

Answer (score 3):

**Identifying Aborted Transactions**

The deadlock condition should result in both transactions responsible for the deadlock being aborted. I generally see deadlocks with Informatica's push down optimization attempting to create temporary views in parallel and deadlocking on the DBC table(s) required to create the views. Like your situation, our Informatica situation is completely random. We can go weeks or months without an abort due to deadlock.

You can find suspect transactions by querying the DBQL Log table for transactions with an `ErrorCode = 2631` (*Edit: Fixed error code*) and `ORDER BY StartTime DESC`. This will give you every transaction that was aborted due to a deadlock. The transaction pairs that resulted in the deadlock should be fairly close together if not paired together by the sort.

If your DBA's have restricted the views against the historical DBQL data in anyway it could be obstructing your ability to find the root cause. If that is the case you will need to work with your DBA Team to pinpoint the problem. It is not uncommon for query information to be restricted to developers because of the information that is contained within the SQLText for a given query. This is just something to consider asking if your query doesn't yield any results.

**Identifying Why Aborted Transactions May Be Occurring**

*Note: This is not an exhaustive list.*

The worse thing about deadlock conditions such as these is that they typically occur at random. Murphy's Law stipulates that these random occurrences will take place when you are sleeping, on vacation, or some other event where you don't wish to be disturbed. Depending on your particular situation you may be able to simply resubmit the transaction(s) that were deadlocked.

This will require you to first understand how you are arriving at the deadlock condition.

- If it is two transactions attempting to manipulate the same record does your data model support slowly changing dimensions so you have a record of each change taking place?
- If it is a read transaction and an update transaction accessing the same record can you adjusting your locking granularity and duration to minimize the chances?
- Are you using `ACCESS` or `READ` locking?
- Are your `SELECT` statements accessing the table through a 1:1 view that employs `ROWHASH` `ACCESS` locking thereby allowing the optimizer to escalate locking from the most granular level to level needed by the transaction in question? (e.g. `LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS SELECT * FROM DBC.DBCInfo;`)
- *Removed suggestion for ROW LOCKING on UPDATE STATEMENT.*

**Handling Aborted Transactions**

Depending on the circumstances surrounding your deadlock condition you can elect for your process to attempt to resubmit the failed transaction a pre-determined number of times. You may have a situation where one process may resubmit and the other may have to remain in a failed state for someone else to verify before proceeding. The former may be your web application and the latter may be a complex ETL stream that can't be restarted blindly.

You should log somewhere that this occurred or have some other reporting mechanism in place to track these incidents.

Comment: So I tried querying for that error code (which is actually `2631`) and the only SQL that showed up is within the transaction I opened.  However, I think I figured out how to trigger the error, just not why it happens.  See update to my answer.

Comment: I updated my question.  I appreciate the time you've put in so far, but if there's nothing more you can do then I'd understand.  I need to get this resolved by this weekend since we're deploying this release, so I'll definitely be updating this question with what I find out.

Comment: DBC.DBQLogTbl actual table name

Answer (score 0):

In relational databases, aborted transactions are not errors per se, but merely a request for the client to retry the transaction from the start because a different, concurrent transaction may have changed conditions that have already been observed by the client issuing the now-aborted transaction. By occasionally allowing transactions to be aborted (and retried by the client), the underlying relational database can make significant performance optimizations, such as allowing many transactions to run concurrently even though this leads to a small chance of deadlock.

Why doesn't the database server retry the transaction itself in these cases? Because the client might be using the data returned from one query in the transaction to influence what kinds of updates to do in subsequent updates within the same transaction. Thus the responsibility for retrying transactions lies with the client in the rare (but perfectly normal and expected) cases where transactions are aborted.

So the answer is: aborted transactions are perfectly normal, and you are simply supposed to retry them from the client-side. But as Rob noted, this may be easy or hard depending on the kind of transaction you're doing (e.g. if you're doing a 2-hour ETL process, you might want to figure out how to reduce the likelyhood of deadlocks instead).